# Override CSS ValidationMessageFor

Tags: c#, forms, asp.net-mvc-4

I can't seem to manage to put a new css in a validationMessageFor in my Ajax form...

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "Success", OnFailure = "Fail" }))
{

<div class="separaror">
    <div class="line1">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
        <br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)

    </div>

    <div class="linha2">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        <input type="button" id="btnCancel" value="Cancel" />
    </div>
</div>
```

}

My css

```
.field-validation-error {
color: #e80c4d;
font-weight: bold;
}

.field-validation-valid {
display: none;
}

input.input-validation-error {
border: 1px solid #e80c4d;
}

input[type="checkbox"].input-validation-error {
border: 0 none;
}

.validation-summary-errors {
color: #e80c4d;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 1.1em;
}

.validation-summary-valid {
display: none;
}
```

It doesn't override.. Why is that? Any help would be appreciated!
I copied the css directly from the default Asp MVC 4 application from visual studio,
I have no idea why this doesnt work.
The application I'm doing is not the default application from mvc 4, so there must be something I'm missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `.input-validation-error` for validation for inputs

This is how you do it

```
.input-validation-error{ background: pink; border: 1px solid red; }
```

If you style up the `.field-validation-error` it will change the validation error message(s).

```
.field-validation-error{ color: red; font-weight: bold; }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I put this css , but it's not overriding the validationMessageFor and textBoxFor on the form, there's something elso to be done?

Comment: The only problem is that It has to be on the same file of the form.. that's weird